Hybris - Adding Service product to main product (Price =0)
I would like to know what is the best approach to add service products to a main product.
Say for example, in Autocare we have Standard Oil Change (Main Product) and Synthetic Oil change (Main Product) and there are services products tied to it like tire pressure check, wheel balance, Air filter inspect, etc.
Cost of service is calculated after the service.
When the user adds Standard Oil change to the cart, it would show as cost of the services = 0.
On completion of the service cost is defined as 100$.
(Modify transactional cost of the product after the order creation)
Appreciate your help on this. Advance Thanks!!!
Still reviewing the option.
